# Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. thrown at UserPrincipal

Tags: asp.net-mvc, active-directory, adfs

I'm trying to create a new user at the AD. I'm using the following code:

```
        using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, this.DomainName, userWithWMIAccessRights, userWithWMIAccessrightsPassword))
        {
            UserPrincipal user = new UserPrincipal(context);
            user.DisplayName = Newusername;
            user.Name = Newusername;
            user.Enabled = true;
            user.SetPassword(passwordOfThenewUser);
            user.Save(); //<-- throws exception InnerException = {"Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))"}
            return user;
        }
```

I set up the userWithWMIAccessrightsPassword like that:

- userWithWMIAccessrightsPassword is member of Enterpirse Admins, Domain Admins and Domain Users
- Ran dcomcnfg from the command prompt.
- Selected Windows Management Instrumentation from the list of services.
- Updated custom permissions by adding userWithWMIAccessrightsPassword account from the Security tab and gave him fully rights.

The webapplication is hosted on the same machine as the AD runs. When I debug the webapplication with Visual Studio the user and the password is set without problems.

When the webapplication is deployed on the AD machine the function which creates the user throws an {"Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))"} at the code line which sets the password. The user is created and not enabled and without a password.

Why do I get Access denied, when the PrincipalContext is using an AD user with fully rights?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it seems that PrincipalContext is != impersionating.

I could solve the issue with:

1.) set the container of the PrincipalContext and call ValidateCredentials(this.UserName, this.Password,ContextOptions.Negotiate).

2.)

```
using (new Impersonator(this.UserName, this.DomainName, this.Password, LogonType.LOGON32_LOGON_SERVICE, LogonProvider.LOGON32_PROVIDER_WINNT40))
        {
            using (var context = CreatePrincipalContext())
            {
                UserPrincipal user = new UserPrincipal(context);
                user.DisplayName = username;
                user.Name = username;
                user.Enabled = true;
                user.SetPassword(password);
                user.Save();
                return user;
            }
        }
```

But I'm still confused about the need of the impersonator class with the Principalcontext. I thought the PrincipalContext replaces the impersionate class.